# Как в консоле линукса распарсить команду top по %cpu

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Не хватает мозгов дополнить команду, чтобы она корректно парсила %cpu приложения.
Проблема сейчас заключается в след.: есть данная команда

```
top -p ${pid} -b -d1 -n1 | grep -i "Cpu(s)" | head -c21 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '%' -f1
```

которая корректно выводит %cpu при загруженности приложения менее > 10%, результат вывода: `0.8`. Как только нагрузить приложение < 10%, результат вывода: `us,`. Вопрос в том, как это можно обойти? 
Вывод команды (без использования `| cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '%' -f1` на момент подачи нагрзуки): `%Cpu(s): 47.9 us, 12.`, чтобы понять, откуда взялся `us,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас пришёл с следующему решению с использованием `bc`:

```
echo "scale=2; `top -p ${pid} -b -d1 -n1 | tail -1 | awk -F" \ '{print $9}'`/`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`" | bc
```

Забираем общее кол-во потребляемого приложением cpu (`top -p ${pid} -b -d1 -n1 | tail -1 | awk -F" \ '{print $9}'`), делим его на кол-во процессоров (`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`) и проставляем кол-во знаков после запятой (`scale=2`)

Comment: *Useless use of cat...*